# How to slowly(like a effect) move a label(image) to click position of mouse in JAVA with swing

Tags: java, image, swing, label, mouselistener

I want to make a GUI program that, when I press mouse button, moves label to the position of pressed X and Y locations. I did that, it was easy, but I want to make it now like a slow moving effect. I tried to do it with `thread.sleep()` but it didn't work. Can you help me with ideas or code? This is my code:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class jGame extends JFrame {

private JPanel contentPane;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                jGame frame = new jGame();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

public jGame() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 568, 459);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    contentPane.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    JLabel robot = new JLabel("");
    robot.setIcon(new ImageIcon("/home/ubuntu/Desktop/robot.png"));
    panel.add(robot);
    panel.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {

        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            robot.setLocation(e.getX() - 25, e.getY() - 40);
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {

        }
    });
}

}
```

And here is the image I use:
[image: robot]

Comment: I would suggest using a timer for this. That way you can adjust the speed to whatever you want.

Comment: Can you show me how to do it in my code or edit some code for simple example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing is half the fun...

1. Store the `startPoint` & `nextStep` as `Points`
2. Initialize a javax.swing.Timer
3. When user clicks, save the Root `startPoint`, set `nextStep` to mouse location and call `timer.start()`.
4. `Timer.actionPerformed()` needs to calculate the `nextStep` Point as it moves back to `startPoint`.
5. if startPoint equals nextStep  call `timer.stop()`

Comment: Can you show me how and where to intialize my Timer to follow mouse clicked please.